# JavaScript redirect function

Tags: javascript

How can I pass argument to function redirect in JavaScript

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function redirectlink(text){
    window.location = "index.php?keyName="+ text;
}
//-->
</script>

<form>

  <button  type="button" id="butt_1"  onclick="redirectlink(KEY_POWER)"> 1 </button>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying? Posting a question, deleting it, and no proper code. Did you read [ask]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done either by using `getElementById` and `addEventListener`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="foo">Click</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("click", function(){
            window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com/q/36933820/5526354")
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

either `onclick`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="foo" onclick="action()">Click</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function action(){
            window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com/q/36933820/5526354")
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello,the problem that i have many URL I want to use one function for all URL so the url must be an argument for the function window.location it's not fixed. I have 3 buttons when i click on the first button it's must redirect me to url:"index.php?keyName=KEY_POWER" the second button to URL: index.php?keyName=KEY_UP etc...

Comment: @Ktarizied am glad it helped! make sure to select the answer which was the most helpful to you as future readers will also find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Using **onclick** is deprecated.

With just only JavaScript (without jQuery / Angular etc.) you can use **addEventListener** on click event.

for example:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('butt_1');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
// your code 
});
```

In this function you can for example get value/txt from this button element and something else which you want.

Comment: [`onclick` isn't deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick).